# How to replicate {cursor: hand; cursor: pointer} in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

It is a common practice in CSS to use `{cursor: hand; cursor: pointer}` for cross-browser reasons. How would you achieve the same effect using jQuery? If you do `$('#foo').css({cursor: 'hand', cursor:'pointer'});` They are object keys and will clobber each other.

Thanks!

Comment: If it was a common practice for cross-browser support 10 years ago, it's no longer necessary now. Every browser supports `cursor: pointer` just fine, including IE6 and newer. The only additional browsers you'll support by including `cursor: hand` are IE4 and IE5, which jQuery doesn't support anyway.

Comment: I agree with BoltClock. But this should work,

`$('#foo').css('cursor','hand').css('cursor','pointer');`

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, didn't realize it was THAT old :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)?

```
.pointer {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}

$('#foo').addClass('pointer');
```

Comment: Yeah you could always do that, but I was hoping for some clever JS only solution, hence the "in jQuery" part.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < '6.0') {
    $('#foo').css('cursor','hand');
} else {
    $('#foo').css('cursor','pointer');
}
```

OR

```
var cursor = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < '6.0') ? 'hand' : 'pointer';
$('#foo').css('cursor',cursor);
```